# Android libgdx falling objects

Tags: android, object, libgdx, smoothing

```
//this is the UPDATE method
public void update(float delta) {
    handlingInput();

    deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    timer += deltaTime;
    if (timer >= 1) {
        buttons.add(new Buttons());
        timer -= 1;
    }

    cam.update();

    Iterator<Buttons> butts = buttons.iterator();
    while(butts.hasNext()) {
        Buttons button = butts.next();
        button.update(delta);
        if (button.getPosition().x > Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) {
            butts.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the render method

```
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    for (Buttons butts: buttons) {
        sb.draw(butts.getButTexture(), butts.getPosition().x, butts.getPosition().y);
    }
    sb.end();
}
```

and this is the UPDATE of the falling objects

```
public void update(float delta) {
    position.x += (int) (300 * delta);
}
```

I have the falling object multiply my delta time so it does not matter if it is lagging. I also tried float, but the problem is that it doesnt go smooth, it just keeps lagging every few miliseconds. I am new and I am unsure of what I am missing!?

Comment: What is the Buttons class? My guess is that instantiating that and dropping some to the GC is causing your hiccups. Are you loading a texture in the Buttons constructor?

Comment: I have a Texture that randomly generates when a button is created, so every button had its own texture that is instatied in the contrsctor! Is that something wrong? Because I tried it on a newer phone and it worked fine and on desktop too... So how should I load a different texture for each button?

Comment: Load all the textures you will need in the create method and have them available for the Buttons to reference. Then you won't be loading them while the animations are running, which will cause stutters.

Comment: well the slutters still happen and I did that. I made an Array of textures in create, passed it to playState, which is where my game logic is, and then each time a button is created it passes in the constrctor the array of textures

Comment: Can you share the code of your Buttons class?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1ZzPdbfh <-- here you go

Comment: That doesn't look like a huge class but you could look into LibGDX pooling to se if it helps.

Comment: Got it somehow working, thanks alot, but now a question that is asked alot, but if I use fitViewport(200, 200, camera), and then use 200, 200 something for all my logic, will the game fit on all android devices automaticly? Or if you could point me into something beginner friendly... thanks alot again!, because then I have to make for each button texture an actual sprite, so I can use setSize...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the `sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);` out of the render method? As far as I know, it can simply be called once, when you create the SpriteBatch, and maybe it's resource expensive and making your game laggy (this might not be the cause, but I can't find anything else which could).

Comment: If you want to make queries from OP, please leave a comment. Post an answer only if you are sure of the requirement and issue

Comment: tried to remove it, same, it is weird, because the movement appears to be smooth but then every few "time" it just laggs...